# For loop over list with strings python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am receiving the following error:
string indices must be integers

I know what it means, but can't seem to fix it. Need the string name as a whole in order to put in positions of i.

```
list_of_strings = ["string_one", "string_two", "string three"]
empty_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in list_of_strings:
empty_df = empty_df.append(i[i['column name'].str.match("whatever")==True])
```

Comment: Your brackets are not matched

Comment: `i['column name']` - `i` is a string, it has no concept of `column name`, that's where it's looking for an integer, because you index strings with integers

Comment: So how do I make "i" behave as a dataframe. Because the string is the exact same name as the dataframe I am trying to access